# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I tried to find some solutions but none of them was working.

The header part:

```
<script src="/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/modernizr.js"></script> 
<script src="/js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="/js/validate.js"></script>
```

The script part:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#post_target" ).autocomplete({
        source:'/classes/user-list.php',
    })
});
```

Also there is one more script in the footer

```
<script src="/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see I placed the jquery first , I tried to use jquery no conflict..but that was not working too. Thx

Comment: What plugin should be supplying the autocomplete function? You're getting the error because there is no reference to the library supplying the autcomplete function.

Comment: Are you trying to use jqueryUI's autocomplete? If so, then you need to include jquery-ui...Notice that jquery and jquery-ui are separate packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the error comes when you're missing a reference to the library that contains the autocomplete function, please check if you've implemented all the jQuery libraries you need.

If you're trying to use the autocomplete from jQueryUI, you need to import the jQueryUI library, which is available [here](http://jqueryui.com/download/).

After you have downloaded it, just import it like with all the other libraries, like

```
<script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js"></script>
```

And remember to place this import tag after the jQuery import tag.